# How to Encode String to display color text( based on the prefixes within String)

Tags: java, string, javafx, text, colors

I'm new to Java and I'm struggling with the following task.
Im writing an app which encodes the input of a user(depending of one's choice) into code that is compiled in Command Line interpreter in Quake III Arena ,that enables player to color nick's letter depending to the following char prefixes(for example "^0Black^3Yellow)
^0 BLACK
^1 WHITE
^2 GREEN
^3 YELLOW
^4  BLUE
^5 CYAN(LIGHT BLUE)
^6 MAGENTA PURPLE
^7 WHITE
[That is how app looks in current stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH9h6.jpg)

The code work properly but i want to generate a Color Text based on the input, that will preview the current look of the Nick by clicking generate.

I gave up after several attemps and i have no clear idea how to approach in this subject.Anything would be highly appreciated.I wish i was specific enough.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your regex is simple: ^[\\^]\d{1}\w+. This means: Start with ^, then follows by a digit of 1 number, then any text:

^0TEXT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to extract the portions of the text, and then build a text flow with different colored text elements in it.

Here's a demo. The regex looks for two different named groups: an optional `^` followed by a (named "colIndex") digit, and then (named "text") any non-zero sequence of characters not equal to `^`. The listener on the text field just iterates through the matches and builds the `Text` elements.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldRegexExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Color[] colors = new Color[] {Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.PURPLE};

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\^(?<colorIndex>\\d))?(?<text>[^(\\^\\d)]+)");

        TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow();

        textField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(newValue);

            textFlow.getChildren().clear();

            while(matcher.find()) {
                String color = matcher.group("colorIndex");
                String text = matcher.group("text");
                Text t = new Text(text+" ");
                if (color != null && color.matches("\\d+")) {
                    int colIndex = Integer.parseInt(color);
                    if (colIndex >= 0 && colIndex < colors.length) {
                        t.setFill(colors[colIndex]);
                    }
                }
                textFlow.getChildren().add(t);
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(5, textField, textFlow);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]